# how to cancel an android studio update

Tags: android, android-studio

since I installed the lasted update of android studio I have been receiving a lot of errors while trying to run and building the project. I wonder if there is a solution to restore android studio to the older version

Comment: You can change the gradle settings and have fun :)

Comment: Could you please precise how I should do that ?. I'm a beginner

Comment: Can you please specify what kind of error are you facing?

Answer (score 0):

You could uninstall android studio and download its older version from [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/archive). But the better treatment is to keep the latest version and solve errors.